# Error subscribing to push notifications in published app (but not debug version)

Tags: c#, azure, push-notification, uwp

I never get this error in Debug mode which is why I never noticed it until I published my app to the store and tried the published version which crashed.  At first I tried to attach the debugger to a running copy of the store app, but even with full symbols loaded, there was no useful error message.  So I tried using Release mode to generate the application package and I attached debugger to the local Release copy and I got the same result when I try to subscribe to notifications, but this time I was able to get an error with stack trace, it fails with the following message

Message

> "HTTP request failed.
>   HTTP Details:
>   Status: 400\nReason: Bad
>   Request
>   Full content: `400`The specified
>   resource description is
>   invalid..TrackingId:cfbbefdd-1c0e-41a2-bd47-0e0f60c40adb_G13,TimeStamp:4/18/2017
>   3:22:48 AM"

StackTrace

> StackTrace    "   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.RegistrationManager.d__24`1.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in
>   f:\\dd\\ndp\\fxcore\\CoreRT\\src\\System.Private.CoreLib\\src\\System\\Runtime\\ExceptionServices\\ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line
>   61\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\\dd\\ndp\\fxcore\\CoreRT\\src\\System.Private.Threading\\src\\System\\Runtime\\CompilerServices\\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   187\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\\dd\\ndp\\fxcore\\CoreRT\\src\\System.Private.Threading\\src\\System\\Runtime\\CompilerServices\\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   156\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) in
>   f:\\dd\\ndp\\fxcore\\CoreRT\\src\\System.Private.Threading\\src\\System\\Runtime\\CompilerServices\\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   128\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.RegistrationManager.<RegisterAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.CoreLib\src\System\Runtime\ExceptionServices\ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line
>   61\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   187\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   156\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   128\r\n   at
>   Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Messaging.NotificationHub.d__10.MoveNext()\r\n
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.CoreLib\src\System\Runtime\ExceptionServices\ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line
>   61\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   187\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   156\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   128\r\n   at
>   myApp_Win10.Notifications.d__4.MoveNext() in
>   D:\SkyDrive\SOURCECODE\myApp\WindowsUniversal\Notifications.cs:line
>   53\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw() in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.CoreLib\src\System\Runtime\ExceptionServices\ExceptionDispatchInfo.cs:line
>   61\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   187\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   156\r\n   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd(Task task) in
>   f:\dd\ndp\fxcore\CoreRT\src\System.Private.Threading\src\System\Runtime\CompilerServices\TaskAwaiter.cs:line
>   128\r\n   at myApp_Win10.Views.Settings.d__4.MoveNext()
>   in
>   D:\SkyDrive\SOURCECODE\myApp\WindowsUniversal\Views\Settings.xaml.cs:line
>   72"   string

And my code where I try to subscribe

```
   private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            this.progress.IsActive = true;
            string category = (string)App.localSettings.Values["notificationCategory"];

            List<string> categories = new List<string>();
            categories.Add((category).Replace(" ", "_"));
            foreach (string s in categories)
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Categories: " + s);
            //subscribe to new channel Uri

            Notifications notifications = new Notifications("myHub", "MyEndpoint");
            var result = await notifications.SubscribeToCategories(categories);
            this.progress.IsActive = false;
            if (result != null)
            {

                MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Successfully subscribed to notifications for " + category , "Subscribed!");

                await md.ShowAsync();


            }
            else
            {
                MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("Subscribe to notifications failedd. Please try again later.  If the problem persists please send feedback to the developer. Thank you.", "Failed!");

                await md.ShowAsync();
            }

        }catch(Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

I'm using **DefaultListenSharedAccessSignature** and I tried to regenerate the Primary connection string, but same result.

**EDIT** - Here is my Notification class

```
public class Notifications
{

    private NotificationHub hub;

    public Notifications(string hubName, string listenConnectionString)
    {
        hub = new NotificationHub(hubName, listenConnectionString);
    }

    public async Task<Registration> StoreCategoriesAndSubscribe(IEnumerable<string> categories)
    {
        return await SubscribeToCategories(categories);
    }

    public IEnumerable<string> RetrieveCategories()
    {
        var category = (string)App.localSettings.Values["notificationCategory"];
        var categories = new List<string>();
        categories.Add(category);

        return categories;
    }

    public async Task<Registration> SubscribeToCategories(IEnumerable<string> categories = null)
    {
        var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

        if (categories == null)
        {
            categories = RetrieveCategories();
        }

        // Using a template registration to support notifications across platforms.
        // Any template notifications that contain messageParam and a corresponding tag expression
        // will be delivered for this registration.

        const string templateBodyWNS = "<toast><visual><binding template=\"ToastText01\"><text id=\"1\">$(toastMessage)</text></binding></visual></toast>";

        return await hub.RegisterTemplateAsync(channel.Uri, templateBodyWNS, "",
                categories);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

According to your mentioned exception, the paramters are not correct when try to register for notifications.

> HTTP request failed. HTTP Details: Status: 400\nReason: Bad Request Full content: 400The specified resource description is invalid.

Please have a try to use fiddler to get detail error info. On my side it works both on release and debug mode. More detail about how to use Notification Hubs to for notifications, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/Azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-windows-notification-dotnet-push-xplat-segmented-wns).

Note: please remove all of the breakpoints before publish app.
If it is possible, please share your regitry code.

[image]

```
public class Notifications
    {
        private NotificationHub hub;

        public Notifications(string hubName, string listenConnectionString)
        {
            hub = new NotificationHub(hubName, listenConnectionString);
        }
        public async Task<Registration> StoreCategoriesAndSubscribe(IEnumerable<string> categories)
        {
            ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["categories"] = string.Join(",", categories);
            return await SubscribeToCategories(categories);
        }
        public async Task<Registration> SubscribeToCategories(IEnumerable<string> categories = null)
        {
            var channel = await PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();

            if (categories == null)
            {
                categories = RetrieveCategories();
            }

            // Using a template registration to support notifications across platforms.
            // Any template notifications that contain messageParam and a corresponding tag expression
            // will be delivered for this registration.

            const string templateBodyWNS = "<toast><visual><binding template=\"ToastText01\"><text id=\"1\">$(messageParam)</text></binding></visual></toast>";

            return await hub.RegisterTemplateAsync(channel.Uri, templateBodyWNS, "simpleWNSTemplateExample",
                    categories);
        }
        public IEnumerable<string> RetrieveCategories()
        {
            var categories = (string)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values["categories"];
            return categories != null ? categories.Split(',') : new string[0];
        }
```

Comment: Ok I added my Notifications class to my original post, code looks almost the same as yours.  I debug again and it seems to fail at this line in SubscribeToCategories method PushNotificationChannelManager.CreatePushNotificationChannelForApplicationAsync();  I will keep investigating.

Comment: I don't know if this help or not but I recently had to regenerate my certificate in the Package.appmanifest. (Created new Test Certificate) then I had to re-associate my app to the store in order to publish it. I'm thinking perhaps that is why my app can no longer register a Channel Uri with WNS. What do you think? What reminded me of this was this post stackoverflow.com/a/31131733/1462656 However I tried to regenerate secret key and update WNS settings on Azure, but nothing helped.  I can subscribe in Debug, but not in Release.

Comment: I got it to work finally, although not exactly sure what the problem was in the first place, I decided to update all my Nugetpackages, and also remove and reinstall the nugget package that handles Azure notifications.  Then I also removed all breakpoints and the Disgnostics.Debug entries.  I tested and Release mode worked again.  I think it was the nuget packages that were the problem, although not sure what.